# Difference between "CharSequence interface" and "CharSequence key"

Tags: java, charsequence

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(CharSequence key);
```

If I search online to find out what CharSequence is, I get all the information about the CharSequence interface.
I can't understand what does a CharSequence interface has to do with CharSequence key used in Actions class?

Thanks

Comment: The Interface of CharSequence is the definition of the type. Actions.keyDown(CharSequence key) says that the parameter key is any variable of type CharSequence.

Comment: So is ("Keys.SHIFT, Keys.UP...etc) considered CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer or StringBuilder?  Thanks

Comment: No idea. You should check the JavaDoc for Keys.

Comment: The point is that _it doesn't matter what the implementation is_. That's why the API accepts a `CharSequence` and not a specific implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDocs for CharSequence: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Under implementing classes, you will see

```
CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder
```

So by defining Action as taking a CharSequence parameter, it means that you can use any of the CharSequence implementations above, or possibly create your own. It is a way to loosely couple classes / class dependencies and make code more reusable and durable.